# Database backup with codeigniter 4

Tags: database-backups

I want to take a backup of the database in CI 4.

```
$model = new class extends \CodeIgniter\Model {
        protected $table      = 'form';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    };
    $db = \Closure::bind(function ($model) {
        return $model->db;
    }, null, $model)($model);
    
    $util = (new \CodeIgniter\Database\Database())->loadUtils($db);
```

now I want to save the table in SQL format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function backup_db(){
$model = new class extends \CodeIgniter\Model {
protected $database      = 'options';
protected $primaryKey = 'option_id';
    };
    $db = \Closure::bind(function ($model) {
    return $model->db;
    }, null, $model)($model);

    $util = (new \CodeIgniter\Database\Database())->loadUtils($db);
    echo $util->getXMLFromResult($model->get());
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more info, aside from the code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently CI4 doesn't directly support full database backup. You can do it for each of your models (one for each table) and use [this from docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html)